# ASP.NET MVC: Textboxes don't get highlighted when I access Modelstate.AddModelError Manually

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have this property

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Add this property")]
public string MyProperty {get; set;}
```

When I use modelbinding validation like this

```
UpdateModel(myModel);
```

Then when there is an error the form is re-displayed, and the textbox representing MyProperty is **highlighted** (i.e. red borders and pink background). The **Html.ValidateMessageFor()** display also error message next to the textbox.

But, when I do it manually, like this

```
if(string.NullOrEmpty(myModel.MyProperty))
  ModelState.AddModelError("MyProperty", "Custom message");
```

If there's an error, I still get the error message. But only **Html.ValidationSummary()**) displays list of error on top of the page. But the texbox is not highlighted anymore and the **Html.ValidateMessageFor()** doesn't display anything at all.

Is there anything I can do to fix that?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After over 2 days without any answer, I suspected that I didn't ask this question the right way. So, [I asked differntly and got an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475556/how-asp-net-mvc-applies-input-validation-error-to-a-textbox-when-the-form-is-red). I'll then answer myself this question in case someone have the same problem.

The whole thing was about not prefixing keys when the model is a composite one. For instance, in my case:

```
public class FormViewModel
{
  public OrganizationData organizationData { get; set; }
}
```

And OrganizationData is defined by

```
public class OrganizationData
{
  public string OrganizationName { get; set; }
}
```

So I should have done this

```
if(string.NullOrEmpty(formViewModel.organizationData.OrganizationName))
   ModelState.AddModelError("organizationData.OrganizationName", "Name can't be empty")
```

But, I omitted the **prefix** organizationData and rather did

```
ModelState.AddModelError("OrganizationName", "Name can't be empty")
```

On the view, the Html helper will check the ModelState to know if there is error associate to his key. So, if that's the cae, it highlights itself. In that case, **organizationData.OrganizationName** and **OrganizationName are different**. So the textbox doesn't highlight itself.

One more thing. I didn't experience the same with **TryUpdateModel()** because, not only it uses AddModelError() internally, but also uses an algorithm that can figure out the right key.

I guess I got the lesson. I was able to solve some other pending problem just by knowing this mechanism.

Thanks to Darin Dimitrov and Ian Galloway.