# .input-validation-error to a textbox when the form is redisplayed for failed value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I've asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325515/mvc-asp-net-best-way-to-get-52-textbox-key-values-from-view-to-controller) to know why, in my application, textboxes are being highlighted (i.e. red border and pink-shaded backgroung are applied to the textbox) when I use modelbinding to validate the model (**TryUpdateModel()**) but not when I validate manually (**ModelState.AddModelError**). It has been 2 days now without any answer. I've tried every thing myself without succes. So, I decide to ask the question differently.

The way I understand IT, here's how ModelBinding treats a request.

1. ModelBinding get incoming values from httpcontext
2. It instantiate an object of that model
3. Tries to parse those values to the object
4. If there's someting wrong with a property, it uses ModelState.AddModelError to mark properties that has something wrong with them.
5. Re-displays the view

Here's my question When the form is re-displayed:

**What's being done for the textboxes whose values are not valid to get highlighted?**

I know that there's few classes in Site.css, such as **.input-validation-error** and **.field-validation-error** that get applied to the textbox. Maybe ModelBinding uses internally a command such as AddCss("#MyTextBox", ".input-validation-error").

If I know how it works, I can (maybe) aplly it manually and solve my problem.

**EDIT**

As requested by @Ian Galloway, here's the code

```
public class RegistrationController : Controller
{
  public FormViewModel formViewModel;
  private RegistrationService _registrationService = new RegistrationService();
  private SaveService _saveService = new SaveService();
  protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var serialized = Request.Form["formViewModel"];
        if (serialized != null)
        {
            formViewModel = (FormViewModel)new MvcSerializer()
                            .Deserialize(serialized);
            TryUpdateModel(formViewModel);
        }
        else
            formViewModel = (FormViewModel)TempData["formViewModel"] 
                            ?? new   FormViewModel();
    }
  protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Result is RedirectToRouteResult)
            TempData["formViewModel"] = formViewModel;
    }
    public ActionResult SetUpOrganization(string cancel, string nextButton)
    {
        if ((nextButton != null) && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (formViewModel.navigationData.IsAReview)
                return RedirectToAction("RequestPreview");
            return RedirectToAction("ChooseTypeOrganization");
        }
        ViewData["Cities"] = _registrationService.Get_Cities();
        formViewModel.navigationData.NextAction = "SetUpOrganization";
        return View(formViewModel);
    }
  public ActionResult ChooseTypeOrganization(string backButton, string nextButton)
    {
        if (backButton != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("SetUpOrganization");
        }
        if (nextButton != null)
        {
            if (formViewModel.navigationData.IsAReview)
                return RedirectToAction("RequestPreview");
            return RedirectToAction("DocumentsPresented");
        }
        ViewData["TypeOrganization"] = _registrationService.Get_AllTypeOrganization();
        formViewModel.navigationData.NextAction = "ChooseTypeOrganization";
        return View(formViewModel);
    }
    public ActionResult DocumentsPresented(string backButton, string nextButton)
    {
        if (backButton != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ChooseTypeOrganization");
        }
        if (nextButton != null)
        {
            //Validation
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(formViewModel.registrationData.DocumentPresente))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("DocumentPresente", "Veuillez préciser votre
                  autorisation");
                return View(formViewModel);
            }
            //Navigation
            if (formViewModel.navigationData.IsAReview)
                return RedirectToAction("RequestPreview");
            return RedirectToAction("PeopleRecommended");
        }
        formViewModel.navigationData.NextAction = "DocumentsPresented";
        return View(formViewModel);
    }
  public ActionResult PeopleRecommended(string backButton, string nextButton, string deleteButton,
                                          string deletePerson, string addPerson)
    {
        if (backButton != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("DocumentsPresented");
        }
        if (nextButton != null)
        {
            ModelState.Clear();
            if (formViewModel.registrationData.PeopleRecommended.Count == 0)
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Il faut absolument designer un responsable pour la requête");
            //
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (formViewModel.navigationData.IsAReview)
                    return RedirectToAction("RequestPreview");
                return RedirectToAction("StateObjectifs");
            }
            else
            {
                return View(formViewModel);
            }
        }
        //
        if (addPerson != null)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                formViewModel.registrationData.PeopleRecommended.Add(
                    _registrationService.Translate_PersonToBeAdded_Into_Person(formViewModel.personToBeAdded)
                    );
                formViewModel.personToBeAdded = null;
            }
            else
            {
                formViewModel.navigationData.NextAction = "PeopleRecommended";
                return View(formViewModel);
            }
        }
        if (deleteButton != null)
        {
            formViewModel.registrationData.PeopleRecommended.RemoveAt(int.Parse(deletePerson));
        }
        ViewData.ModelState.Clear();
        formViewModel.navigationData.NextAction = "PeopleRecommended";
        return View(formViewModel);
    }
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult StateObjectifs(string backButton, string nextButton)
    {
        if (backButton != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("PeopleRecommended");
        }
        if (nextButton != null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(formViewModel.registrationData.Objective) ||
               string.IsNullOrEmpty(formViewModel.registrationData.RequestDetails))
            {
                 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(formViewModel.registrationData.Objective))
                     ModelState.AddModelError("Objective", "Vous devez préciser l'objectif de votre requête");

                 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(formViewModel.registrationData.RequestDetails))
                     ModelState.AddModelError("RequestDetails", "Vous devez préciser le contenu de votre requête");
                 return View(formViewModel);
            }

            if (formViewModel.navigationData.IsAReview)
                return RedirectToAction("RequestPreview");
            return RedirectToAction("StateDeadLine");
        }
        return View(formViewModel);
    }

    public ActionResult StateDeadLine(string backButton, string nextButton)
    {
        if (backButton != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("StateObjectifs");
        }
        if (nextButton != null)
        {
            if (formViewModel.registrationData.ChooseDifferentDeadLine)
            {
                if (formViewModel.registrationData.DifferentDeadline == null ||
                    string.IsNullOrEmpty(formViewModel.registrationData.ReasonsForDifferentDeadLine))
                {
                    if (formViewModel.registrationData.DifferentDeadline == null)
                        ModelState.AddModelError("DifferentDeadline", "Clickez pour choisir une nouvelle date");
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(formViewModel.registrationData.ReasonsForDifferentDeadLine))
                        ModelState.AddModelError("ReasonsForDifferentDeadLine", "Expliquez brievement pour quoi ce changement");

                    return View(formViewModel);
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("RequestPreview");
        }
        formViewModel.navigationData.NextAction = "StateDeadLine";
        return View(formViewModel);
    }
  public ActionResult RequestPreview(string backButton, string nextButton, string reviewInput, string save)
    {
        if (backButton != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("StateDeadLine");
        }
        if (nextButton != null)
        {
            _saveService.Save_FormViewModel(formViewModel);   
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        if (reviewInput != null)
        {
            formViewModel.navigationData.IsAReview = true;
            return RedirectToAction(RedirectHelpers.RedirectReviewAction(formViewModel.navigationData, reviewInput));
        }
        ViewData["TypeOrganization_Summary"] = _registrationService.Get_TypeOrganization_Summary(
                                                                formViewModel.registrationData.TypeOrganizationID                                                                   );
        if (save != null)
        {
            _saveService.Save_FormViewModel(formViewModel);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        formViewModel.navigationData.NextAction = "RequestPreview";
        return View(formViewModel);
    }
}
```

**EDIT number 2**

I have choosed one of the view (as all of them experience the same issue). The view is called **StateObjectifs.aspx**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<!-- Script Begin -->
<script src="../../Scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "textareas",
        theme: "advanced",

        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing: true
    });
</script>
 <!-- End Script -->
<fieldset id = "StateObjectifs">
    <legend>Etape 5:</legend>
    <div id = "left-pane" style = "width:700px">
    <%using (Html.BeginForm("StateObjectifs", "Registration"))
  { %>
   <%: Html.ValidationSummary() %>
  <% = Html.Serialize("formViewModel", Model) %> 
  <table>
    <tr>
        <th><% = Html.LabelFor(x=>x.registrationData.Objective) %></th>
        <td><% = Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.registrationData.Objective) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(x =>x.registrationData.Objective, "*")%></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan = "2"><% = Html.LabelFor(x =>x.registrationData.RequestDetails) %></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan = "2">
            <% = Html.TextAreaFor(x =>x.registrationData.RequestDetails, 10, 75, null) %>

        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  <div id = "right-pane">
        <ul>
            <li>Les cases pour lesquelles le titre se termine par (*) sont obligatoires</li>
            <li>Pour mieux vous servir, veuillez décrire clairement de manière concise
                votre requête. Par exemple: <i>Les données de l'USAID sur le secteur santé pour l'année 2009</i></li>
        </ul>  
      </div>
      <div class = "clear"></div>

  <fieldset>
            <% Html.RenderPartial("NavigationView", Model.navigationData); %>
  </fieldset>
</fieldset>
<%} %>
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Can you post the view code for the text box, and the c# code where you're manually adding the model error please?

Comment: @Ian Galloway: Check the edit above

Comment: @Ian Galloway: I try to post the code but the formating is not good. So I'll try to select some of the code and write them by hand, instead of copying/pasting everything.

Comment: Cheers: I'll need the part of the view where you render the text box as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually this *highlighting* is performed by the html helpers that render the textboxes. It checks if there's an error in the model state with the given key and it adds the necessary CSS classes if necessary.

Comment: Hello @Darin Dimitrov. Good to have you again. if this higlighting is performed by the html helper, why this helper is not detecting the error when I use ModelState.AddModelError, instead of TryUpdateModel?

Comment: If you use `TryUpdateModel` is there an error added to the ModelState dictionary with the given key? If no then probably that's the reason why the HTML helpers don't pick it up.

Comment: Yes. Actualy, both TryUpdateModel and ModelState.AddModelError add errors to the ModelSate. And, in both cases, Html.ValidateSummary() displays error messages on top of the form. However, Html.validateMessageFor() only works when I use TryUpdateModel, not with ModelState.AddModelError(). The same way, Textboxes are highlighted only with TryUpdateModel, not with ModelState.AddModelError().

Comment: Are you using some complex model types? If so is in both cases the key that points to the error element in the `ModelState` dictionary the same? Probably there's a prefix added to the key which matches exactly the id of the input when using `TryUpdateModel` which is not the case when you manually add the error using `AddModelError`. The `ValidateSummary` helper displays **all** error messages in the model state.

Comment: Yes. Since I'm serializing data while sending them to view back and forth. I've created 1 model that include 3 sub-model. So that I've to worry only about serializing 1 model, the super-model. I've posted already the controller. Do you need also the view? the model?

Comment: @Darin: Thanks. I couldn't think that a small details could paralyzed everything. I added prefix, and everything is working now.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the problem you are having is that the "key" parameter you pass into ModelState.AddModelError must match the name of the matching control on the form.

(Otherwise, how would you expect the view engine to know which control to render in an error state?)

Comment: @Ian Galloway: I've start suspecting that I didn't write correctly the key. Check the second edit then.

Comment: Hm. Can you have a look in your markup and tell me what the name of Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.registrationData.Objective) comes out as?

Comment: <input id="registrationData_Objective" name="registrationData.Objective" type="text" value="" />

Comment: @Ian Galloway: Thanks. from the markup above, I've used "registrationData.Objective", instead of just "Objective". Now, it works. i didn't imagine it could be that easy.

Answer (score 1):

The highlighting is being done by CSS which applies to the text-box. So you need to add the css below:

```
.input-validation-error {
border: 1px solid #ff0000;
background-color: #ffeeee;
```

}